# How to change a setting to true in a PHP file?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have an Apache2 web server with PHP 5.5 installed.
My default PHP settings is `display_error = 0` (I don't need globally displayed errors) but I need it on in specific PHP files.

I tried with:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

and it's not working.

Can someone tell me how can I make it show errors in specific PHP files?

Comment: This should be enough normally. Maybe your file doesn't have an error?

Comment: @modsfabio i am try to force some error writing some no syntax logic and not showing error...

Comment: `ini_set` sets a configuration value, shared accross the whole application - it's not possible to only allow `display_errors` for specific files.

Answer (score 0):

> i am try to force some error writing some no syntax logic and not showing error...

To show  **parse** errors in PHP you have to put this on your php.ini

```
display_errors = on
```

My advice is to avoid displaying errors on production servers but log them all. So you can later inspect and fix bugs from yoursite-error.log file.
You should be concerned if your applications has warnings, errors etc. IMHO it is a bad idea to focus your attention only on few files instead of them all.

Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with ini_set()), it won't have any effect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed.